# NullPointerException to take photo on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, camera, file-descriptor

I have an app that makes a photo and paint in an `ImageView`. According to the used device, the action fails or not. I get the error back to the photo (NullPointerException). The device with error has Android 4.2.2

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE:
        File imageFile = getTempFile();
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Bitmap bm = null;
            Uri selectedImage = null;
            if (imageReturnedIntent == null){    /** CAMERA **/

                selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            }
            else{                                /** ALBUM **/
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            }

            int sampleSize = 7;
            do{
                sampleSize -= 2;
                bm = decodeBitmap(selectedImage, sampleSize);
            }while(bm.getWidth() < MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY && sampleSize > 1);
            saveBitmap(imageFile, bm);
            replaceImage(bm);

            saveLista();
        }
    }
}

private Bitmap decodeBitmap(Uri theUri, int sampleSize) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =null;
    try {
        fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor( theUri, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
            fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);

    return actuallyUsableBitmap;
}
```

`theUri = file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.XXX.XXX/files/552f5980e610620bd8e803ab/UserImages/19/19.png`

`fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor() = null`

```
04-16 15:46:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 15:46:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at XXX.XXX.XXX.decodeBitmap(ModuleListaCompraFotografia.java:212)
04-16 15:46:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at XXX.XXX.XXX.onActivityResult(ModuleListaCompraFotografia.java:188)
04-16 15:46:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
04-16 15:46:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
```

Comment: post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: run your project and post logcat here

Comment: Please, show us the error line from:

`XXX.XXX.XXX.decodeBitmap(ModuleListaCompraFotografia.java:212)`
and

`XXX.XXX.XXX.onActivityResult(ModuleListaCompraFotografia.java:188)`

Comment: `Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
            fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);` because **fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor() == null**

Comment: @user4152 Where are you passing the URI here, `bm = decodeBitmap(selectedImage, sampleSize);`

Comment: selectedImage is URI

Comment: `getTempFile()` check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html), I hope it helps

Comment: See the message that comes from here: `e.printStackTrace();`